# Code to manually apply an Email restriction on a coupon in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I have an e-commerce site using wordpress and woo-commerce, now using the smart-coupon woocommerce plugin extension is there a way for me to create a credit coupon/gift-card (that initially has no email restriction) and manually assign the email of the current user as the email restriction for it the first time the gift-card is being used.

I'm trying to create a vooucher system using the giftcard as vouchers to purchase products in my store.

Comment: I'd suggest this a question for a woo-commerce specific forum.

Comment: I tried that a couple of days ago, couldn't get any help there. So now i'm here.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have any code to show what you were using, try this.

```
$coupon_code = 'some-code-I-created';
$user = wp_get_current_user();//Get the current user object
$coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );//Get the coupon object
$emails = $coupon->get_email_restrictions();//Returns an empty array or array of emails
$emails[] = strtolower($user->billing_email);//Add user's billing email address to the array
$emails = array_filter($emails);//Remove empty values
array_unique($emails);//Remove any duplicate values
$coupon->set_email_restrictions($emails);//Set the coupon's array with the updated array
$coupon->save();//Save the coupon
```

In case I'm adding email addresses in bulk (like using array_merge() instead of adding one address at a time), it's always good to make sure the array is clean by removing any empty values or duplicate values before updating the coupon object with it.

Also, WooCommerce compares the billing address in all lowercase but not the restricted emails in the coupon, so be sure when adding it to your coupon that you add it as all lowercase so they validate correctly. [Source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/15676). This bug may be fixed in the future, but until then...